# Is it possible to get access to riemann dashboard without proxy

Tags: riemann, riemann-dashboard

I have installed riemann dashboard, but can access to it only from localhost.
All I have found is to advices to setting up apache/nginx to access to dashboard from the remote host.

I was looking on `bind` parameter, but don't know what to set here to get access to dashboard from remote hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set bind to 0.0.0.0:port-number

them check It with netctl -nlp and make sure it's not still binding to 127.0.0.1:port-numbrr-here